# Start service with JobScheduler on Android O

Tags: android, firebase, android-intentservice, android-jobscheduler

I'm trying to start a IntentService to register to a firebase cloud messaging on Android O.

On Android O it's not allowed to start a Intent Service "in a situation when it isn't permitted" and every one tells me to use a JobService but not how to use it.

**What constraints should the JobInfo.Builder have in order to have a "situation where it's permitted", i keep getting the same IllegalStateException**

Here's my JobService

```
@Override
public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, RegistrationIntentService.class);
    getApplicationContext().startService(intent);
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
    return false;
}

public static void scheduleJob(Context context) {
    ComponentName serviceComponent = new ComponentName(context, MyJobService.class);
    JobInfo.Builder builder = new JobInfo.Builder(MyJobService.JOB_ID, serviceComponent);
    builder.setMinimumLatency(1 * 1000); // wait at least
    JobScheduler jobScheduler = context.getSystemService(JobScheduler.class);
    if(jobScheduler != null) jobScheduler.schedule(builder.build());
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using support library version 26.1.0 or higher you have access to the `JobIntentService` which is similar to an `Intent Service` with the added benefits of the job scheduler, you do not need to manage anything other than starting it.

According to the docs

> Helper for processing work that has been enqueued for a job/service. When running on Android O or later, the work will be dispatched as a job via JobScheduler.enqueue. When running on older versions of the platform, it will use Context.startService.

You can find out more details here [JobIntentService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/JobIntentService.html).

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.JobIntentService;

public class JobIntentNotificationService extends JobIntentService {

    public static void start(Context context) {
        Intent starter = new Intent(context, JobIntentNotificationService.class);
        JobIntentNotificationService.enqueueWork(context, starter);
    }

    /**
     * Unique job ID for this service.
     */
    static final int JOB_ID = 1000;

    /**
     * Convenience method for enqueuing work in to this service.
     */
    private static void enqueueWork(Context context, Intent intent) {
        enqueueWork(context, JobIntentNotificationService.class, JOB_ID, intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleWork(@NonNull Intent intent) {
        // do your work here
    }
}
```

And the way you call it is

```
JobIntentNotificationService.start(getApplicationContext());
```

You will need to add this permission for pre Oreo devices

```
<!-- used for job scheduler pre Oreo -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Comment: Thanks to your help. Works successfully on all android version

Comment: I have a MainActivity.java, how can I start JobIntentNotificationService from MainActivity.java ?

Answer (score -1):

Firebase actually has a dedicated service for receiving messages called `FirebaseMessagingService`. [This Firebase page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive) should contain all the info to get you started in that regard.

Aside from that, you're trying to access the application context from the Service, while you should be using the base context of the parent service:

```
    getApplicationContext().startService(intent);
```

to

```
    startService(intent);
```

If you want to launch certain jobs from the `FirebaseMessagingService`, look into their [JobDispatcher](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android#user-content-firebase-jobdispatcher-) library which is pretty great.